# Getting registered users in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

#### Background

I have a LightSwitch application that needs to implement a lightweight task management system. Something where a `Manager` could come in and create a task and then assign it to someone else. While I can do the query to find tasks created by the logged in user (see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2010/09/07/filtering-data-based-on-current-user-in-lightswitch-apps.aspx) blog on MSDN) it doesn't fully answer my question.

#### Question

How can I get the current list of **registered** users (the ones that the `SysAdmin` adds using the `Form Auth` selection and adds them in the Administration screen) in a drop down list and then 'assign' tasks to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Membership.GetAllUsers()` in your server project. You'll need to reference `System.Web.Security` to get access to it. [This article](http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2011/08/linking-lightswitch-data-to-logged-in.html) talks about doing it in a WCF RIA Service but Generic File Handlers also work.

Alternatively, if you want to filter the list of users by what permissions they have, you can use a LINQ query on `this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.Permissions`. [This forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/043c23fd-ae72-44e5-8944-b18b315cb84c/how-to-get-list-of-users-having-a-certain-permission?forum=lightswitch) goes into a little more detail on constructing a possible query for specific users.